# Looping through a Word Document and Replacing a String with PageBreak

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, page-break

I want to replace every occurrence of the string "#PAGEBREAK# with an actual `pagebreak`. This is what I came up with:

```
Sub InsertPageBreak()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "#PAGEBREAK#"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            .Execute
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What actually happens: The string "#PAGEBREAK#" is exchanged for an empty string. The .Find works as intended but I get the error message:

> Method or Object not found

on the

```
.InsertBreak Type:= wdPageBreak
```

What methods could be used here in which way?

Comment: Use the code in the Answer, as for the code you have pasted, it will only replace the text once, if you want to replace for all the occurrences use the second code that I have provided, which loops and replaces all the occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work For you:

```
Sub InsertPageBreak()


    ActiveDocument.Range.Select

        With Selection.Find
                .Text = "#PAGEBREAK#"
                .Execute
        End With

        If Selection.Find.Found Then

            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        End If
End Sub
```

---

If you want to Replace all of the "#PAGEBREAK#", use this below code:

```
Sub InsertPageBreak()


   ActiveDocument.Range.Select

    Do

    With Selection.Find
            .Text = "#PAGEBREAK#"
            .Execute
    End With

        If Selection.Find.Found Then

            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        Else: Exit Sub

        End If
    Loop


End Sub
```